# Accessing IBM Informix from .Net Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, database, ado.net, informix

We need to implement an integration with an old database from `IBM` called `Informix`. Given that, we installed the Client SDK (version `4.10 FC4DE`) by IBM and implement a simple console application to test the data access methods. It works fine with `.Net ADO.NET Provider for Informix`, `ODBC` 64 Bits and `OleDb` (by `Ifxoledbc` driver).

When we try to run it over a web application (asp.net MVC with the same version of .Net Framework we just tested on console app - 4.6 version), we got the following error:

> Could not load assembly 'IBM.Data.Informix' or one of its dependencies...

And if I try to run it via ODBC, it shows me:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

And it just does not work with.Net ADO.NET Provider, ODBC, or OleDb. None of this works on the web app, but in the Console everything is fine.

Something strange happens when I add the reference on a project. When I add the reference on the Console App, on the properties window of the reference of `IBM.Data.Informix` it shows me the dll version is the 3.0.0.0 and on the console is the 4.0.0.0 been the same file path.

My question is, how can I investigate it properly and understand what dependency is missing on the web application case?

Thank you.

Comment: After changing Net version make sure you fully recompile application.  Often changing version of Net the dependencies in the compiler doesn't fully recompile.  I usually make a copy of the project bin folder and then delete the bin folder which  forces everything to recompile.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I did it. I `clean` and `rebuild` the solution. I remove the entire bin folder. I check the code generated on the csproj file and the version of the assembly is correct. But when I right click and check properties, it shows the right path but the version 3.0.0.0. I do not know what can I try anymore =/

Comment: Open the proj file with notepad in the project folder and make sure the correct Net Version is being targeted.    Not every dll gets updated with each version of Net.  Only the libraries that change.  So in Net 3.5 Drawing 2.0 dll is used, but in Net 4.0 Drawing 4.0 dll is used.

Comment: Yes, I did it and no success. I created a new asp.net project adn add the reference. It shows as 3.0 but in the bin folder, it shows the 4.0 dll. When I compile, I got that error. I dont know why and I dont know what I can do anymore. Console app it works fine.

Comment: Make sure you have the INFORMIXDIR\bin directory on your System PATH. The web server may run with a different environment than a normal user, so it may not have the Informix directory in the PATH. That means the .NET provider (IBM.Data.Informix.dll) will fail to load the required libraries.

So, I suggest to add "c:\Program Files\Informix Client-SDK\bin" to your System PATH and also create INFORMIXDIR as a System variable with "c:\Program Files\Informix Client-SDK"

Comment: The compile copies the reference items from the source location into the bin folder.  So the source location must contain the dll.  So open the proj file with notepad and check where the source is located. You could always check you entire file system for the wrong dll.

Comment: @jsagrera Yes, I have setted the PATH and Environment Variables as you said. And I think for this reason it works on the console app. I updated the error on my first post with the error I got in aspnet application with ODBC.

Comment: As SYSTEM variables? Also, make sure you bounce the webserver so it can pick the changes.
The Informix .NET provide requires all the libraries (and files) in the INFORMIXDIR, otherwise it's not going to work. The fact that you mentioned that ODBC and OLEDB also fail, makes me believe that there is a problem loading any of those files.
Another thing to look for is the architecture. You need to match whatever your Webserver uses. AnyCPU can't be used with Informix .NET as it's not fully managed (it needs native libraries, either 32-bit or 64-bit)

Comment: Well, I have defined as 64 bits execution and I checked the INFORMIXDIR (value: `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Informix\Client-SDK`) on both (System and Users Environments Variables). I also add on the PATH the `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Informix\Client-SDK\bin` where there are a log of files and utilities. Inside the bin folder I have the netf40 e netf20 (I am using the dll of netf40). The code works on Console App but does not work on Asp.net. I am running on Visual Studio with IIS Express. Do you have any suggestion to configure IIS Express to get it? On the future it will run on IIS in prod.

Comment: Umm...If you have "C:\Program Files (x86)" that means 32-bit CSDK. You have to build in 32-bit (x86) mode and switch the webserver to 32-bit.
Or (which is the best option) get the 64-bit CSDK (something like 4.10.FC12) installed on that machine.

Comment: I had to change the IIS Express to run on 64 bits on visual studio `Tools / options / Projects and Solutions / Web Projects` and check the option: `Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express` and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: When running web applications, it must execute on 64 bit because the Client SDK is 64 bits.

To make sure you have a Web Application running on 64 bit, on Visual Studio, go to `Tools` / `Options` / `Projects and Solutions` / `Web Projects` and **check** the option `Use 64 bit version of IIS EXpress for web sites and projects`.